# htmlparser2 - replace values of all href attributes inside html string

Tags: javascript, attributes, href

I have HTML string which I would like to parse to DOM, replace **values** of all specific `href` attributes inside `a tags` and stringify back with serializer.

NPM Library [htmlparser2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/htmlparser2) will probably do the job, but I cannot figure out, how to use it.

So far I have been playing with `domhandler` and `domutils`. Especially `domutils` has quite a lot methods, but I have no idea, if any of these is right for me. I can parse string to DOM, filter all `href` attributes, but that is not enough.

Can you please give me a hint, whether is **htmlparser2** suitable for my needs?

Comment: that package is quite esoteric imho. For your use case, using [node-html-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-html-parser) is easier and will suit your needs

Answer (score 1):

```js
// pure js
function parse_DOM_and_replace_target_href(domtext = "") {
    let parser = new DOMParser(),
        XMLS = new XMLSerializer(),
        new_document = parser.parseFromString(domtext, "text/html"),
        target = new_document.querySelectorAll("whatever selector you need");
    
    // editing selected element's href in new_document
    target.forEach(ele => {
        // or use regex: ele.href.match(reg)
        if (ele.href.includes("...")) {
            ele.href = ele.href.replace("...", "...");
        }
    });

    // serialize
    new_document = XMLS.serializeToString(new_document);

    // release memory, DOMParser is expensive
    parser = XMLS = null;
    
    return new_document;
    // if you put result in other variable and return
    // you should do (new_document = null) too
    // new_document is a complete page in memory, expensive
}
```